# How to use symbols instead of fractions for the number row?

Tags: gboard

For Gboard, the default symbol when you long press a number in the number row is to show fractions. Is it possible to change this behavior to symbols instead similar to a normal keyboard where 1/!, 2/@, 3/#, 4/$, 5/%...etc. I know these symbols are already present when you long press the letter keys but I just want to know if there is an option for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some languages have a *PC keyboard* layout that allows long-pressing the first row (e.g. numbers) as quick access to its Shift modifier.** Otherwise, there is no option to add alternative keys to the existing keyboard layouts.

Steps to change the keyboard layout:

1. Open Gboard settings

   - Android Settings - System - Languages & input - On-screen keyboard (steps may differ depending on the device model and Android version)
   - Tap the **cog wheel** icon from the Gboard keyboard directly
2. Select **Languages**
3. Select an existing language, or add a new keyboard
4. Swipe the layout options to find the **PC** layout.

[image]

Note that this layout *hides the pop-up character hint* on the keys, so the user must have already remembered the characters to use them efficiently.